# Menu popup helper cannot be used without anchor

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragments

I want to use popup to a menu item in action bar. It's everything ok when I use this in the Activity but when I switch to fragment I get:

```
MenuPopupHelper cannot be used without an anchor
```

my fragment:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_filter:
            createCategoriesPopupMenu(item);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_sort:
            createSortPopupMenu(item);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}


private void createSortPopupMenu(MenuItem item)
{
    PopupMenu popup;
    
    final View menuItemView = getView().findViewById(item.getItemId());
    
    Log.wtf("d","item getitemid"+item.getItemId());
    
    if (menuItemView == null)
    {
        Log.wtf("d","menuItemView==null view"+view.findViewById(item.getItemId()));
        Log.wtf("d","menuItemView==null getAc"+getActivity().findViewById(item.getItemId()));
        
        //final View searchItemView = getView().findViewById(R.id.action_search);
        //popup = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), searchItemView);
    }

        popup = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), menuItemView);

    Menu menu = popup.getMenu();
    
    addSortMenuItems(menu);

    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item)
        {
            onSortMenuItemClick(item);
            return true;
        }
    });

    popup.show();
}   
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.issues_list_menu, menu);

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

console output(assert):

> 07-08 14:08:16.659: A/d(1677): item getitemid2131165600 07-08
>
> 14:08:16.659: A/d(1677): menuItemView==null viewnull 07-08
>
> 14:08:16.663: A/d(1677): menuItemView==null getAcnull

I did't forgot setHasOptionsMenu(true); in onCreateView()
and `view` is inflated layout from `onCreateView()`

Comment: are you sure menuItemView is not null?

Comment: @blackbelt I know it's null, but don't know why.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok i found solution in xml menu file in item which we want to add popup we need to set

```
android:showAsAction="always"
```

becouse popup works only on icons in action bar not in menu. Also use getActivity().findView... not getView().findView...

Comment: `android:showAsAction="always"` is not the reason but the main problem is not using `getActivity().findView...`. Edit your answer I have tested.

Comment: @ahmadalibaloch The main problem IS the null action view. So showing the menuitem as action view solves the issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can change

`final View menuItemView = getView().findViewById(item.getItemId());`

to

`final View menuItemView = getActivity().findViewById(item.getItemId());`